# Can not connect to server via FTP

Tags: android, ftp, sftp

> I am getting the following  error :

java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /139.59.67.108 (port 21): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)

Here is my code

```
 try
                    {
                        FTPClient con = null;
                        con = new FTPClient();
                        con.connect("139.59.67.108");
                        Log.v("checkLogin", "succeeded");
                        if (con.login("xxxx", "xxxx"))
                        {
                            con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                            con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);



                            ///data/data/com.prd.inspirationslate/databases
                            String data = "/data/data/com.prd.inspirationslate/databases";  //path on device

                            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));


                            Log.v("upload result check", "succeeded");

                            boolean result = con.storeFile("/vivekm4a.m4a", in);
                            in.close();
                            if (result) Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
                            con.logout();
                            con.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

> trying to upload file via ftp on server . On filezilla I can easily connect
>
> Log trace
>
> > java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /139.59.67.108 (port 21): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) 
> >     W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124) 
> >     W/System.err:     at
> >     java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183) 
> >     W/System.err:     at
> >     java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163) 
> >     W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:592)
> >     W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128) 
> >     W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:178) 
> >     W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:150) 
> >     W/System.err:     at
> >     org.apache.commons.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultSocketFactory.java:53)
> >     W/System.err:     at
> >     org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:162)
> >     W/System.err:     at
> >     org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:250) 
> >     W/System.err:     at
> >     com.prd.inspirationslate.LoginActivity$2$1.run(LoginActivity.java:120)
> >     W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
> >     W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect
> >     failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)  W/System.err:     at
> >     libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)  W/System.err:     at
> >     libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)  W/System.err: 
> >     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)  W/System.err: 
> >     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)  W/System.err:  ...
> >     11 more

Comment: Show us full exception callstack + Are you using Apache Common Net library? + Are you connecting with FileZilla from the same machine/device that runs the Java code? + Where do the slash in "/139.59.67.108" come from?

Comment: here is the full stacktrace : yes Apache Common net library ......no the machine is different for java code and server....also added log trace ..thanks for help in advance

Comment: So first test connectivity from the same machine/device.